# Caching Sequence from database to reduce db calls

Tags: java, sql, jooq

we are developing batch application using JOOQ. Application requires to call sequence to get next value for persisting large number of records. This will definitely be overhead to the performance. Does JOOQ has any built in way of handling this or any other alternative to reduce the sequence call to cache the sequence generated value?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Are you just assuming that it will be a performance problem? Or did you actually test it? Fetching sequence values is typically extremely fast and unless you are on a slow network (with a high latency) I don't think it will be a big problem (unless you need to fetch millions of sequence values per second)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I've seen tremendous improvement when fetching a batch of sequence values from PL/SQL (*inside of oracle!*) prior to running inserts (using `FORALL`), rather than calling `nextval` on each insertion via trigger or identity or whatever. Of course, I will have to write a blog post now, to support this. Now, with a client round trip, this improvement might be irrelevant, given the much higher overhead of JDBC communication...

Comment: @LukasEder I would put the `nextval` directly into the INSERT statement ;)  (and we still don't know if ManjuGH uses Oracle or Postgres or SQL Server or DB2)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I would, too, but the case I had at the time didn't offer that possibility because sequence values had to be fetched quite a bit before the actual insert statement. Forgot why. There *was* a reason.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're planning on fetching e.g. 100 sequence numbers into the client in one go, in order to use them in a single, subsequent batch operation. This could be achieved using the following jOOQ statement, e.g. in Oracle:

```sql
SELECT seq.nextval
FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <= 100;
```

Or with jOOQ

```java
ctx.select(SEQ.nextval())
   .connectBy(level().le(100))
   .fetch();
```

Depending on the RDBMS you're using, you will need to replace the `connectBy()` syntax by standard `WITH` syntax for recursion, or `generate_series()` in PostgreSQL, or otherwise query a table that has the number of rows in it that you need, as a workaround.

Comment: Detail: The equivalent jOOQ example should use `le()` rather than `lt()`, but SO doesn't accept one char edits :-)

Comment: @knutwannheden: Sneak in a meaningless formatting :) Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Is there any example on how to attach sequences fetched like above to batch query @LukasEder ?

Comment: @pppavan: Not sure. But you can ask a new question and then there will be an example :)